# Teradata : Update table values with join and if clause

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on a Teradata system in which I have 2 tables, `Apple` as `A` & `Ball` as `B`. `Apple` has 2 columns `primId(integer)` and `updateValue(INteger)`. `B` only has `primId(integer)`. What I am trying to do is, when `A.primId=B.primId`, then set `updateValue=1` else to `0`.

```
Table Apple:
Columns : Primary-key primId(Integer)
Other Columns : updateValue-(Integer)

Table Ball :
Columns : Primary-key primId(INteger)
```

My query so far :

```
update apple from apple a, ball b set updatevalue=1 where a.primId=b.primId;
```

I am getting a invalid query error, and I have no else clause yet. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Does Teradata really support UPDATE FROM?

Answer (score 1):

Teradata doesn't support Outer Joins in an Update, but you could do it in FROM:

```
UPDATE apple
FROM
 (
   SELECT a.primId, CASE WHEN b.primId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS x
   FROM apple AS a
   LEFT JOIN ball AS b
     ON a.primId = b.primId
 ) AS src
SET upDateValue = src.x
WHERE apple.primId = src.primId
```

Probably more efficient:

```
UPDATE apple
SET upDateValue
  = COALESCE((SELECT 1 FROM ball WHERE ball.primId = apple.primId),0);
```

But IMHO the best performing solution will be two Updates within a *Multi Statement Request* (MSR):

```
UPDATE apple
SET upDateValue = 1
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT 1 FROM ball b WHERE apple.primId = b.primId)
;UPDATE apple
SET upDateValue = 0
WHERE updatevalue <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid implicit join syntax(comma separated) and use the appropriate syntax of joins:

```
UPDATE apple a
LEFT JOIN ball b
 ON(a.primId=b.primId)
SET updatevalue= CASE WHEN b.primId is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ;
```

Comment: I am getting an error, something missing between a and left.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

```
UPDATE a 
FROM apple a
LEFT JOIN ball b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.updatevalue = CASE WHEN b.id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I was late to answer and didn't notice your one. Sorry

Comment: I am getting an error, something missing between a and left.

Comment: I want to compare the case when a.id=b.id, not b.id greater than 0.

Comment: It is compared in the joins and case is just for returning 0 and 1 based on matched and miss matched data.

Comment: @WeareBorg, please use updated one, hope it will work as expected.

Comment: @Suraz why left outer join? I think requirement here is inner join.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara In the question we have to update records when matched then with 1 else 0. So we should use left join to retrieve records from left table in both case and update accordingly by adding condition. By inner join we can able to update matched values only. If I understood the requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

This query is a rather direct translation of your question:

```
update apple
    set updatevalue = (case when exists (select 1 from ball b where apple.primId = b.primId)
                            then 1 else 0
                       end);
```

Comment: Where is b declared?

Comment: Update failed 3771, illegal expression in when clause of case expression is what I am getting. Any idea? Is the select 1 statement correct, or should it be select primId instead of select 1.

Comment: @WeareBorg . . . This is pretty standard SQL.  I would expect Teradata to accept it.

Comment: It doesn't, any ideas? As teradata doesn't seem to have the standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there. You just need to change alias.

```
update a
from apple a
left outer join ball b 
on a.primId=b.primId
set updatevalue= (case when b.primId is not null then 1 else 0 end) ;
```

Try this.